# MySQL Splitting Column Results into Dynamic Columns in View

Tags: mysql, view

I'm not sure if this is possible using MySQL alone, or whether PHP or similar would be required. What I am trying to produce is a view that is dependent upon the amount of information that is present in one table to determine how many columns are displayed in the view.

I have a Components table containing the following fields:

```
CM_ID (The component ID)
CM_CODE (A specific company assigned code)
CM_DESCRIPTION (A brief description of the component)
FORMAT_ID (A referenced FK)
ITEM_ID (A referenced FK)
```

An example of a select from the Component table is:

```
CM_ID   CM_CODE CM_DESCRIPTION      FORMAT_ID       ITEM_ID
1       111111  Technical Manual    1 (280 Page A4 Book)    32
2       111112  Schematic Diagram   2 (A3 Fold-out sheet)   32
3       222223  Technical Manual    1 (280 Page A4 Book)    2
4       222224  Price Guide         25 (32 Page A4 Book)    2
5       333335  Instruction Manual  33 (220 Page A5 Book)   44
```

The view I'm trying to get is based upon displaying items (from the master items table). Each item will have one or many components (which are brought in with an FK on CM_ID)

I have produced the following view:

```
SELECT  i.item AS Item,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cm.CM_CODE, _utf8', ',cm.CM_DESCRIPTION, _utf8,', ',f.FORMAT_DESCRIPTION) SEPARATOR '; ') AS Components
FROM item AS i
JOIN components AS cm ON i.ITEM_ID = cm.ITEM_ID
JOIN format AS f ON cm.FORMAT_ID = f.FORMAT_ID
```

This will obtain results in the form of:

```
Item    Components
2       222223, Technical Manual, 164 Page A4 Book; 222224, Price Guide, 32 Page A4 Book
32      111111, Technical Manual, 280 Page A4 Book; 111112, Schematic Diagram, A3 Fold-out
44      333335, Instruction Manual, 220 Page A5 Book
```

Only the 2 columns are returned (Item & Components), due to the concatenation. What I'd like to be able to do is to form separate columns for the item's components that are dependent upon the actual amount of components.

Example output:

```
Item    Component1                                  Component2
2       222223, Technical Manual, 164 Page A4 Book  222224, Price Guide, 32 Page A4 Book
32      111111, Technical Manual, 280 Page A4 Book  111112, Schematic Diagram, A3 Fold-out Sheet
44      333335, Instruction Manual, 220 Page A5 Book
```

Note that Item 44 only has one component, therefore, it has no data in the component2 column. Should a select be done on JUST item 44, then ideally, there would be no mention of the Component2 column at all. Similarly, if another item came along with 4 components, then the output would automatically scale to form 4 Component columns.

I've looked at a number of ways to acheive this, but none seems to be exactly right. Is this possible?

Many Thanks in advance

Iain

UPDATE **

Ok, I'm trying to set a defined number of columns and do the select on that but still having difficulty. I've added another field to the Components table:

```
CM_ORDER
```

Which can be used to differentiate between components for the same item (in theory).

I know this isn't right, but I was trying to get something along the lines of the following to work:

```
SELECT  i.item AS Item,
cm.CM_CODE AS Component_Code1 WHERE cm.CM_ORDER = 1,
cm.CM_DESCRIPTION AS Component_Description1 WHERE cm.CM_ORDER = 1,
cm.CM_CODE AS Component_Code2 WHERE cm.CM_ORDER = 2,
cm.CM_DESCRIPTION AS Component_Description2 WHERE cm.CM_ORDER = 2
FROM item AS i
JOIN components AS cm ON i.ITEM_ID = cm.ITEM_ID
JOIN format AS f ON cm.FORMAT_ID = f.FORMAT_ID
```

Not sure how I'd get the associated "Format" info in there too. Obviously, MySQL isn't at all happy with me putting multiple WHERE clauses in the SELECT statement so I tried using CASE instead, with as much success (none).

There must be a way to split it out into separate columns in the same query without using a scripting/coding language.

Trying to achieve the result:

```
Item    Component_Code1    Component_Description1    Component_Code2    Component_Description2
2       222223             Technical Manual          222224             Price Guide
32      111111             Technical Manual          111112             Schematic Diagram
44      333335             Instruction Manual
```

- with the associated "Format" data too.

Am hoping that this can be done

Cheers

Iain

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, what you want to do is not possible in SQL.  SQL requires that the columns in a query be pre-defined.

One possible approach is to use dynamic SQL for this purpose.  You would calculate the maximum number of components in the data, and then use this information to create a query.

You already are trying the second approach, which is to use semi-colon separated lists of comma-separated lists.

The final approach is to settle on some maximum number of components, and build the query for that.  So, you could show, say, the first three components.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. It's confirmed what suspected in that SQL won't do that without help from something else. I'll have to try and put together something in PHP that does this. Cheers

Comment: I was looking at the 3rd option you said Gordon, where you settle on the maximum number of components. I'm probably going about this the wrong way entirely, but am having difficulty selecting into the separate columns still in the same query. I've amended the question above with the new details

Comment: @user2001184 . . . Alas, even when I was writing that option, I realized that it is a bit hard to do in MySQL, because MySQWL lacks the `row_number()` function.  To pivot using the third option, you need some way of getting a sequential number.  It is possible with correlatated subqueries, for instance, but doing it at the application layer may be the most reasonable choice.